# Why can a query periodically take 10 times longer to execute?

Tags: postgresql

There is a query:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xml_files t1

    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM xml_files t2
              WHERE t1. "id" = t2. "id" AND
                t1. "mydate" < t2. "mydate"
            )
    AND t1.insert_status IS NULL
   AND t1.section_name='users' AND t1.region IN ('Moscow') AND t1.xml_date >= to_date('2016', 'YYYY') AND t1.parsing_status IS NULL
```

When I execute this query in SQL it can execute 10 times for ~90 seconds, but at 11 it can execute in 5 and then continue to execute in 5.

I don't understand the reason why it takes so long to execute in the beginning. I would understand if after the first time something was cached, but for some reason the 1st time is not enough. And after ~1 hour execution time can back to 90 seconds.

Is there some sort of optimizer in the database or some other cunning logic?

PostgreSQL 13
[image]

Fast execution:
[image]

It seems that there is no hanging query at slow down moment:
[image]

and:
[image]

**upd**: it's bug in Dart PostgreSQL driver

Comment: There could be a caching effect happening here, but first I would also check to see what other processes might be using Postgres here.

Comment: I do not have other processes. I found this behavior just when I was looking for the reason why processes that use the database hung up

Comment: Does your actual query have any parameters? Are you using JDBC?

Comment: After process is stop working, I am checking dump of plain text sql directly in SQL Manager (Valentina Studio). So query as is as in my example. First few attempts it process very slowly (the reason of my service stop working is timeout)

Comment: Does every execution have identical values for all parameters?  (And if so, why are you running exactly the same query over and over)?

Comment: What is the plan for one of the fast executions?

Comment: @jjanes yes I am running same query over and over. I tried to kill hanging app that execute this request and it become fast again. I do not see any logic. But during the count request app do not do noting more.

It can did some insert operation hypothetically before count, but I do not see how can how can they interfere with (they are not so complex)

Comment: Is that table being queried/updated heavily?

Comment: Every 0.1 seconds I am getting UPDATE and INSERT query. But they not heavy. If I restart my micro-service and trying to COUNT (when Insert and update comes) all works fast. It can work fast about 2-3 hours. And than COUNT begin work slowly till I restart my service.

Example of typical UPDATE request:
```
 UPDATE "xml_files" SET "processed_date" = '2021-07-14 19:00', "parsing_status" = 'success', "insert_status" = 'success' WHERE "id" = '21612536'
```